# How to create a local layout for MAUI and install it offline?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, maui, .net-maui

The documentation has provided a simple way to create a local layout for Visual Studio [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2022). For example, the following command can create a local layout for .NET web and .NET desktop development.

```
vs_enterprise.exe --layout c:\localVSlayout --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb --includeOptional --lang en-US
```

I want to create a local layout for MAUI and install it on different PCs. The documentation has not provided any information for MAUI offline download. How can I download it?

Comment: It's directly a part of the new VS 2022, You can find it like you found Xamarin or .Net Core. The name will be MAUI obviously

Comment: @FreakyAli I want the CMD command to download it. I don't know what command can download MAUI. The documentation has not provided a command for MAUI (or even Xamarin).

Comment: I think `--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop` should be changed to download MAUI workload. I don't know what is the correct CLI command.

Comment: From document [Step 2 - Create a local layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#step-2---create-a-local-layout),we can know that the command you posted is for `C++ desktop development` , but if  maui  is based on `.net`.  I think you should have used the wrong command.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I did not use any command. I just only want to know the correct command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem using the following command:

```
vs_enterprise.exe --layout c:\localVSlayout --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.XamarinBuildTools --includeOptional --lang en-US
```

For more information about **VisualStudio Workloads**, go to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools?view=vs-2022).